# $V=L^2(\Omega,Z)$ is path connected

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $V=L^2(\Omega,Z)$. Prove that V is path connected by paths of class 1/2 Holder. I would appreciate it if anyone could give me a suggestion. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $L^2(\Omega,Z)$ here? The space of square integrable functions with values in $Z$ (what is $Z$ then)?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes where Z is the set of integers.

Comment: Simple example, if $\Omega = [0,1]$, and you want to connect $f_0 \equiv 0$ with $f_1 \equiv 1$, use $f_t = \chi_{[0,t]}$, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$. The general principle is the same, but the details get much harder.

Comment: You need some assumption on the measure space $\Omega$. For example, if $\Omega$ is a finite set with the counting measure, the statement is false.

Comment: @PostNoBills: $\Omega$ is a misurable subset of $R$ with the lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea was given by Daniel Fischer in a comment. It suffices to connect every element $f\in L^2(\Omega,\mathbb Z)$ to zero. 
Let $I=\int_\Omega |f|^2$. For $0<t<I$ pick $x=x(t)\in\mathbb R$ such that $\int_{\Omega\cap (-\infty,x)}|f|^2=t$. Let $f_t=f\chi_{(-\infty,x)}$ and also $f_0=0$, $f_I=f$. Observe that for $t<s$ 
$$\|f_t-f_s\|_{L^2}^2 \le s-t$$